# Creating "view all posts" link to show all posts from a specific category in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am new for wordpress. In a page, I am showing 3 latest posts from a specific category. So now, I want to put a "view all posts" link so that visitor can see all post from that category. But I can't do this.

Please help to create this link.

What code should I put in this (href="---") attribute? -->

```
                 <a href="">view all posts</a>
```

Please describe it clearly.

Comment: Use this code get_category_link( "pass the category id here" ) in href.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link

Example from codex:

```
<?php
    // Get the ID of a given category
    $category_id = get_cat_ID( 'Category Name' );

    // Get the URL of this category
    $category_link = get_category_link( $category_id );
?>

<!-- Print a link to this category -->
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>" title="Category Name">Category Name</a>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working. One more questions...   I have created custom post type named "Testimonial". I also showing 2 posts from testimonial. So, now I want to create a "view all posts" link so that visitor can see all testimonial.         In this case, what should I put in (href="--"), <a href="  ">View all testimonials</a>  ?

Comment: [get_post_type_archive_link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_archive_link), that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Last question. I have put a page named blogs in my menu. Though I want to put a link named "go to blog" in a specific place of home page.  Now what should I put  in (href="--"), <a href=" ">go to blog</a> ? please describe clearly.

Comment: Last answer: `<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="Home">Home</a>`, for homepage, for paths relative to homepage change `$path` param. Visit [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url) for more detailed examples, Also, don't forget to close the question if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

it works,

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) );?>"><p> Blog   </p> </a>
```

Create A Page named Blog
And then from Setting> Reading Set Posts page > Blog